# Formula Field not updating a checkbox

Tags: formula-field

I have a checkbox field formula field on a custom object:

IF(Mes__c != NULL , true, false)

But when I create a record that follow this rule the checkbox is not selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ...

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Mes__c))
```

Double check as well that you have selected the option

> Treat blank fields as blanks

(at the bottom of where you define the formula)